# SharePoint All Day Event Inconsistant

Tags: c#, sharepoint, event-handling, executequery

I am using an event receiver to ItemUpdated function to keep two calendars in sync. My code words fine but I notice that when "All Day Event" is exported it gives the new list a different end date.

EX:

### Original List

**Title:** Test1
**End Date:** 1/28/2016 11:59pm
**All Day Event:** Yes

### New List

**Title:** Test1
**End Date:** ***1/29/2016 11:59pm***
**All Day Event:** Yes

How can I stop this from updating the EndDate to the next day?

```js
UpdateItem["Title"] = properties.ListItem["Title"];
UpdateItem["EventDate"] = properties.ListItem["EventDate"];
UpdateItem["EndDate"] = properties.ListItem["EndDate"];
UpdateItem["fAllDayEvent"] = properties.ListItem["fAllDayEvent"];
properties.ListItem.Update();
UpdateItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Hope this helps someone else

```js
UpdateItem["EndDate"] = DateTime.Parse(properties.AfterProperties["EventDate"].ToString(), null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```